# Which databases are supported by PHP?

Tags: php, database

Which databases are supported by PHP? I know PHP supports MySQL, but does it also support other databases like MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc?

Comment: As Andrew said you should check manual before asking questions.

Comment: @vishnu This is an answer site, if an answer can be answered browsing several manuals online you can always post the links to the manuals online and an excerpt where they specify support. Otherwise what is SO good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows machines, you can simply use the included ODBC support and the correct ODBC driver.

On Unix machines, you can use the Sybase-CT driver to access Microsoft SQL Servers because they are (at least mostly) protocol-compatible. Sybase has made a » free version of the necessary libraries for Linux systems. For other Unix operating systems, you need to contact Sybase for the correct libraries. Also see the answer to the next question.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php

Check this page for supported databases. http://phplens.com/adodb/supported.databases.html

Answer (score 8):

Yes, PHP support [numerous of databases](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php).
Tip: you should always check manual before asking questions.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a list of databases supported by PHP:

```
 Access
 Ado
 Ado_Access
 Ado_MSSql
 DB2
 ODBC_DB2
 Vfp
 FBSql
 iBase
 Firebird
 Borland_iBase
 Informix
 Informix72
 LDAP
 MSSql
 MSSqlPO
 MySql
 MySqli
 MySQLt/MaxSql
 OCI8
 OCI805
 OCI8Po
 ODBC
 ODBC_MSSql
 ODBC_Oracle
 ODBTP
 ODBTP_Unicode
 Oracle
 Netezza
 PDO
 Postgres
 Postgres64
 Postgres7
 Postgres8
 Postgres9
 SAPDB
 SqlAnywhere
 SQLite
 SQLitePO
 SyBase.
```

Answer (score 0):

The databases that PHP can natively communicate with are shown here.

```
 Access
 Ado
 Ado_Access
 Ado_MSSql
 DB2
 ODBC_DB2
 Vfp
 FBSql
 iBase
 Firebird
 Borland_iBase
 Informix
 Informix72
 LDAP
 MSSql
 MSSqlPO
 MySql
 MySqli
 MySQLt/MaxSql
 OCI8
 OCI805
 OCI8Po
 ODBC
 ODBC_MSSql
 ODBC_Oracle
 ODBTP
 ODBTP_Unicode
 Oracle
 Netezza
 PDO
 Postgres
 Postgres64
 Postgres7
 Postgres8
 Postgres9
 SAPDB
 SqlAnywhere
 SQLite
 SQLitePO
 SyBase
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php